# SQL Server & ADO Data Types with VB6 - What Size to set for VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT parameter from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, parameters, vb6, output, adodb

Calling a stored procedure from VB6.

```
lcmdADOCommand.Parameters.Append lcmdADOCommand.CreateParameter("@p_user_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8, lobjFPSysUtilsSBO.ExtractUserFromToken(strSessionTokenVal))
          lcmdADOCommand.Parameters.Append lcmdADOCommand.CreateParameter("@p_source_data_XML", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, strXML_Warranty_RSRef)
          lcmdADOCommand.Parameters.Append lcmdADOCommand.CreateParameter("@p_unlock_object_flag", adBoolean, adParamInput, , blnUnlockObjectVal)
          lcmdADOCommand.Parameters.Append lcmdADOCommand.CreateParameter("@p_return_data_flag", adBoolean, adParamInput, , True)

      Set lobjADOParam = lcmdADOCommand.CreateParameter("@p_output_record_XML", adVarChar, adParamOutput, -1, strXML_RecordList_RSRef)
      lobjADOParam.Size = 8000
      lcmdADOCommand.Parameters.Append lobjADOParam
```

With the last output parameter ... if I don't set the size to 8000 I get a runtime error

> "Parameter object is improperly defined.  Inconsistent or incomplete
>   information was provided".

What is the maximum size I can use here in VB6 for an output of VARCHAR(MAX)?
Setting the size to -1 on the input is fine but not on an Output Parameter

Comment: What is `strXML_RecordList_RSRef` ? Are you trying to set the default value or put the return value in a variable? I think it's better to leave off and retrieve later with `strXML_RecordList_RSRef = lcmdADOCommand.Parameters("@p_output_record_XML").Value` - Also might want to try `adLongVarWChar` for parameter type to match Varchar(max)

Answer (score 1):

Use `-1` for size of `adLongVarChar` or `adLongVarWChar` parameters, not `adVarChar` as in your snippet (missing a `Long` in the enum entry name).

Btw, it doesn't matter if direction in `adParamInput` or `adParamOutput` as your Q suggests, i.e. suggesting a problem w/ direction managed to only slow down finding answers here.